# Why does gcroot return System^?

Tags: c++-cli

I have the following code:

```
Internal::ManagedInputData ^getManagedInputData() const { return mInputData; }

private:
    gcroot<Internal::ManagedInputData^> mInputData;
```

and for whatever reason I get compile-time error:

```
error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to
'Internal::ManagedInputData ^'
```

If I comment out that getter the error goes away.

I can't figure out what the problem is for hours, someone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code compiles without any error:

```
#include <gcroot.h>
namespace Foo
{
  public ref class ManagedInputData { };

  class UnmanagedClass
  {
  public:
    ManagedInputData^ getManagedInputData() const { return m_ManagedInputData; }
  private:
    gcroot<ManagedInputData^> m_ManagedInputData;
  };
}
int main()
{
  Foo::UnmanagedClass u;
  Foo::ManagedInputData^ m = u.getManagedInputData();
}
```

So I don´t see a problem... maybe you need to show more code...

See also the documentation of [gcroot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/481fa11f)